# Fixed start date in date slicer in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, visualization, data-analysis

I am creating a date slicer in Power BI where the start date is fixed, and the end date is variable. The slicer should show data from the fixed start date until the selected end date. I am unable to do it. How can I do it?

Thanks,
Regards

Comment: What do you want to fix the start date at? Help us help you by asking a question in the right way. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It may help to show what you have tried, some example data, or screenshots and expected outcomes